# Matplotlib 3d Bar chart: Error: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pandas

I am getting error in my code: "Error: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects". Any idea?
Appreciate your help!

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pandas import *
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

df1= read_csv("/user_home/w_andalib_dvpy/sample_data/3d_sample.csv")

xpos=df1['Date']
ypos=df1['Type']
zpos=df1['Duration']

for z in xpos :
    xs = xpos
    ys = ypos
    color = plt.cm.Set2(random.choice(xrange(plt.cm.Set2.N)))
    ax.bar(xs, ys, zs=z, zdir='y', color=color, alpha=0.8)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.FixedLocator(xs))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.FixedLocator(ys))    

ax.set_xlabel('Type')
ax.set_ylabel('Date')
ax.set_zlabel('Sum of Duration')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please do not open duplicate questions. Instead edit your original question.

Comment: @SaulloCastro: Can you explain about that?

Comment: Please post your Traceback, without it it's quite hard to track it down. Also post minimal CSV data to reproduce.

Comment: /opt/anaconda/envs/np18py27-1.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.pyc in from_bounds(x0, y0, width, height)
    819         *width* and *height* may be negative.
    820         """
--> 821         return Bbox.from_extents(x0, y0, x0 + width, y0 + height)
    822 
    823     @staticmethod

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Comment: @qarma: Date, Duration, Type (e.g. 2013-10-11,32,PTA/n 2013-10-12,10,STV/n 2013-10-13,312,PTA).

Comment: @user3252809 into the question please. my best guess is `ypos` actually contains strings.

Comment: @qarma: yeah...it contains string values...so what should i do here...do i need to convert them?

Comment: you'll need to assign numerical values, for example `(PTA,SVT,XYZ)->(0,1,2)` see only you know how to order your type tags.

Comment: @qarma: i got what you are saying...but i have one more question i want to see on the basis of aggregation by TYPE, DATE columns (i.e. group by DATE, TYPE)...so how i would maintain the dates if i start assigning values for (PTA,SVT,XYZ)->(0,1,2)?

Comment: @qarma:Also, I want you to see my problem below (explained):
 Let's assume there is a table having column names 'ID', 'DURATION', 'DATE', 'TIME', 'TYPE'. The 'TYPE' column have three distinct values namely 'type1', 'type2' and 'type3'. There are 100 records for each 'type1', 'type2' and 'type3' values in the table. I want to display variation of 'DURATION' (we can take sum of duration) with respect to 'type1', 'type2' and 'type3' in 3D bar chart at the same time in the chart.
I want to see type1, type2, type3 in Y position , duration on Z position, and Day (date) on X position